# Issue with Django, Apache, mod_wsgi, and caching CSS files

Tags: python, django

Alright, so I've got a setup which consists of Apache 2.4, Django 2.0.5, Python3.5, mod_wsgi, all running on Debian. When I go to edit a CSS file on my production server, the file doesn't update until I entirely reboot the server it's on. As you can imagine this is tedious and time consuming, so I'd like to find a solution.

Edit: My browser's cache is not the issue. I've tried clearing cache and multiple browsers, definitely a server-side issue.

Here are some config files:

Apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 7aptget.com
Redirect permanent / https://7aptget.com/
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
ServerAdmin w@w.com
ServerName 7aptget.com
ServerAlias 7aptget.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/7aptget.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/7aptget.com/privkey.pem
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown\
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
    #Django Application
    Alias /media /home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/media
    Alias /static /home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/static
    <Directory /home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/website>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
LogLevel info
    WSGIDaemonProcess 7aptget.com python-path=/home/kaden/development/websites/homepage python-home=/home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/env
    WSGIProcessGroup 7aptget.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/kaden/development/websites/homepage/website/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Django wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Django settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.19', '7aptget.com']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':         'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':         'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
    'NAME':
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Please let me know if I've left out some information, and thanks.

Comment: Quick, on top of my head: I suspect your browser caches the css file(s). Simple web search will give you many strategies to stop your browser from caching these files. A quick test would be first to clear your browser cache next time you make a change to your css files and access your webpage again to see if the new css is used.

Comment: Oh, I should've added that I've already cleared my cache and I've tried my site on multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turned out it was CloudFlare's caching. If anyone else is having this issue, make sure you have 'Development mode' enabled in the caching options of your CloudFlare control panel.